# Is ROS 2 compatible with the stage simulator?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I mean we can use stage with ROS1, but can we use it with ROS2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400632/is-ros-2-compatible-with-the-stage-simulator?/) by [alipira](https://answers.ros.org/users/104932/alipira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I more or less rewrote stage_ros as [stage_ros2](https://github.com/tuw-robotics/stage_ros2). It differs from the previous stage_ros interfaces in its modularity.
It is available under https://github.com/tuw-robotics/stage_ros2 and tested for humble. 
An installation description is also available.

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2023-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anthony Goeckner](https://answers.ros.org/users/144793/anthony-goeckner/) on 2023-04-07**:
Thank you for releasing this! You've saved me the effort of creating it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! There is this wrapper library, give it a try: [github link](https://github.com/ymd-stella/stage_ros2)

Edit1: So I found a way better package: https://github.com/woawo1213/stage_ros2, Try this instead!!

---

Originally posted by [ccpjBoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/81361/ccpjboss/) with karma: 46 on 2022-07-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [toffanetto](https://answers.ros.org/users/112593/toffanetto/) on 2022-10-10**:
Hello! When I use woawo1213 package, I'm having problems with the dependencie of Stage in CMake. Did you only installed the ros-noetic-stage package on your machine with ROS2 or did you install all of the ros noetic? Thanks!